# Elementor: Get content from builder with in plugin

Tags: wordpress, elementor, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am writing a plugin for get content from elementor page builder. On front end its showing simply with the_content() but in plugin its not.

I am using get_post(id) for get content but it's showing content from WordPress editor instead of page builder.

Any idea why this???

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Elementor data is saving is meta filed `_elementor_data`.

```
$elementorContent = get_post_meta($post_ID, '_elementor_data',true);
```